# How to convert curl to url in flutter api?

Tags: flutter, curl, dio

never worked before with curl APIs so idk. I need to convert curl to html because I cant use at DIO service. Can someone help me please? thank you

I changed to http url for safety.

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'https://assignment-api.blocked.com.tr/api/v1/product/all' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'access-token: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6InN1bGV5bWFudXJlbjA3QGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImlhdCI6MTY1NDY1NTIzNSwiZXhwIjoxNjgwNTc1MjM1fQ.L3t4E-x-IWlT1wjRx3WNzp-ecX-MsntIl-tRiD9zZmg'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getRequest() async {

  var url = 'https://assignment-api.blocked.com.tr/api/v1/product/all';
  

  var response = await http.get(
    url,
    headers: {
      'accept': 'application/json',
      'access-token: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6InN1bGV5bWFudXJlbjA3QGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImlhdCI6MTY1NDY1NTIzNSwiZXhwIjoxNjgwNTc1MjM1fQ.L3t4E-x-IWlT1wjRx3WNzp-ecX-MsntIl-tRiD9zZmg'
      'Content-Type': 'application/json-patch+json',
    },
  );
  return json.decode(response.body);
}
```